# How can I split string with string array delimiters, keeping delimiter in JAVA

Tags: java, split, delimiter

What I wanna do is

```
str = "POW(MIN(100.21,123)*34,2)";
customSplit(str, string[] {"POW","MIN","(",")",",","*","+"});
```

result :

```
POW
(
MIN
(
100.21
123
)
*
34
2
)
```

1. delimiter is not a char but string
2. has multiple delimiter
3. retain delimiter as token too

Comment: do you need a robust solution or is POW(MIN(double,int)*int,int) how it will always be?

Comment: What did you try so far ? Did you encounter a problem ?

Comment: cause I need use variable for number. for example "MIN(VAL1, VAL2)". and after tokenize, I'll get variable value for calculate.

Comment: What is your code? What is your actual result? What is your expected result?

Comment: sorry.. I was wrong. I don't need POW, MIN as delimiter............. I just had operator array(include *,-,/,POW,MIN,SIN and so on), and I thought it could be used as delimiter. But you guys right. split with *(), would be enough

Answer (score 0):

Why split on POW and MIN? Aren't they just operation names that can change? If so you might try to split on the special characters only, e.g. like this: `str.split("(?=[()*,+])|(?<=[()*,+])")` (of course there probably are a lot more special characters so feel free to expand those classes)

This makes use of zero-length look-aheads and look-behinds, i.e. it splits before or after one of the characters in those character classes but doesn't consume the characters.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I don't see any in the question ;) - in any case, if the character classes are not meant to be complete just as the question isn't complete ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] customSplitter(String str, String[] delimiters) {

    StringBuilder multisplitRegexBuff = new StringBuilder("(");
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < delimiters.length - 1; c++) {
        multisplitRegexBuff.append(Pattern.quote(delimiters[c])).append("|");
    }
    multisplitRegexBuff.append(Pattern.quote(delimiters[c])).append(")");

        return str.replaceAll(multisplitRegexBuff.toString(), "\n$1\n").replaceAll("\n\n", "\n").split("\n");

}
```

*Explanation*:

customSplitter accepts a string and string[], the output of algo then returns string[] delimited by every index of input string[]

The end result of customSplitter method is similar to below for example case

`str.replaceAll("(POW|MIN|\\(|\\)|\\,|\\*|\\+)", "\n$1\n").replaceAll("\n\n", "\n").split("\n")'`

Algo first builds the pattern based on indexes of delimiter array and then applies replaceAll and split.

Comment: read the question, the guy wants an algo which accepts a string and string[], the output of algo should return string[] delimited with every index of input string[], the answer given does exactly that.

if you want to understand how the algo works you should ask politely instead of passing a judgemental statement.